# ScrollView Pagination with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, pagination, swiftui

Is there is a way to do pagination without using List in swiftUI. I found a couple solution but most of them are using list . In my code I don't have list so Im looking for a solution how can I use pagination without using List.

```
    ZStack{
        
        ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: $isAnimating)
        
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators : true){
            
            if isSelected == false {
                
                ProductListSortFilterView()
                
            }
            
            LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(),spacing: 5), count:2), spacing:10 ) {
                
                ForEach(productListArray , id:\.uid) { item in // MARK: Optinal typed changed 
                    
                    ZStack{
                        
                        CatalogBackgroundView()
                        
                        WebImage(url: URL(string: item.image?.medium ?? ""))
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(CGFloat(item.imageRatio ?? 0.6),contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2.5,height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 6)
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.083, trailing: 0))
                        
                        
                        if item.isDiscountActive == 0 || item.isDiscountActive == nil || item.isDiscountDisplay == 0 {
                            
                            Text("\(item.priceSell ?? 0 , specifier: "%.2f" ) \(item.targetCurrency ?? "") +VAT")
                                .font(.system(size: 12))
                                .bold()
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.24, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                            
                            
                        } 
        
    }.onAppear {
        
        if isFinish{
            
            getProductList()
            
        }
        
    }
    .onDisappear {
        
        isFinish = false
        
        productViewModel.currentPage = 0
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Pagination can be handled by a view model, regardless of UIKit or SwiftUI. Simply deal out the slice of the model that you want at that time and reuse the same view to display those results.